# Regular expression to include apostrophe

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a regex that matches names. I need to include an apostrophe in it. A name can contain apostrophes. I included it like

```
/[a-zA-Z-']*/
```

I tested the scenarios and it works fine. 
I just wanted to know if there is any other way to include apostrophe. Or a better way to do this.

Comment: You might post this somewhere at Code Reviews, but here it’s an off-topic.

Comment: This wouldn't fare very well on Code Review as it is only a single regex and there's only so much that can be reviewed about it. At a glance a simple regex like this should be just fine if it works as intended.

Answer (score 1):

I would swap the `-` and `'`.

`-` in regex sets is used for ranges (like you did with `a-z`). To match it literally, you can put it at the start or the end. Apparently, there is another case - if on the left or the right of the dash you already have a range. But this is somewhat obscure, I didn't know about it, had to spend mental effort and so would other people reading your code.

Comment: This is not an answer. It should be a comment.

Comment: @sawa, would it qualify as an answer if I put *"This is the way, but"* at the start?